# Pandas Groupby: How to get the first string

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
dfexample = pd.DataFrame({'OID' : [7, 7, 7, 7],
                      'Category' : ['Plumbing', 'Plumbing', 'Plumbing', 'Plumbing'],
                      'Product_Type' : ['Accessory', 'Shower Accessories', 'Showers', 'Showers'],
                      'Extended_Price' : [20.5, 12.12, 122.45, 225.98]})
```

I want to group this dataframe by 'OID', and get the 'first' string of my object columns (`Category` and `Product_Type`), so in this case `'plumbing'` and `'accessory'`. Desired Output:

```
[in]:dfgrouped

[out]:
OID       Category         Extended_Price     Product_Type
7         Plumbing         381.05             Accessory
```

Right now, I have this which concatenates all the strings together, and doesn't return the 'first' string.

```
def f(x):
return pd.Series(dict(Category = x['Category'].sum(),
                     Extended_Price = x['Extended_Price'].sum(),
                      Product_Type = x['Product_Type'].sum() 
                     ))
dfexample.groupby('OID').apply(f)
```

Comment: You probably want `dfexample.groupby('OID').first()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `first` groupby method returns the first element of each group:

```
dfexample.groupby('OID').first()
```

Apparently you also want to sum the numeric column, so you need to use `agg` to specify which aggregation to use for each column:

```
dfexample.groupby('OID').agg({
    'Category': 'first',
    'Product_Type': 'first',
    'Extended_Price': 'sum'
})
```

Comment: That's really extreme... and he does it in a way that goes undetected, with multiple accounts, that's crazy.

Answer (score 3):

use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with `groupby`

```
dfexample.select_dtypes([object]).groupby(dfexample.OID).first()

     Category Product_Type
OID                       
7    Plumbing    Accessory
```

Answer (score 3):

I would combine [@IanS's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41598760/5741205) and [@piRSquared's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41598738/5741205) great solutions and would try to generalize the solution:

```
In [135]: funcs = {col:'sum' if dfexample[col].dtype == np.number
                             else 'first'
                   for col in dfexample.drop('OID', 1).columns}

In [136]: dfexample.groupby('OID').agg(funcs)
Out[136]:
     Category Product_Type  Extended_Price
OID
7    Plumbing    Accessory          381.05
```

Explanation:

```
In [134]: {col:'sum' if dfexample[col].dtype == np.number else 'first'  for col in dfexample.drop('OID', 1).columns}
Out[134]: {'Category': 'first', 'Extended_Price': 'sum', 'Product_Type': 'first'}
```